# Use inherited method from another module

Tags: perl, module, phantomjs, mechanize

I'm using the module [WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS), which inherits from [WWW::Mechanize](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize). However, it seems that some methods, such as [mirror](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize#mech-mirror), do not work in PhantomJS.

> `Can't locate object method "mirror" via package "WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS" at ...`

How could this method be used through an object from PhantomJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can  see `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS` does not inherit from `WWW::Mechanize`. Instead it tries to mimic the interface of `WWW::Mechanize`, but with phantomjs as the lower layer. Because PhantomJS does all the network access itself instead of `LWP::UserAgent` which underlies `WWW::Mechanize`, you cannot simple reuse the mirror method from `WWW::Mechanize` in `WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS`.

Comment: In this case, I decided to create two objects; `my $url = WWW::Mechanize->new();` and `my $phantom = WWW::Mechanize::PhantomJS->new();`

Comment: @KeplerBR: as long as you have only simple static links to resources and nothing dynamically generated by JavaScript `WWW::Mechanize` is sufficient. But once you need JavaScript `WWW::Mechanize` will not be enough.